# DevExpress SpinEdit not incrementing?

Tags: devexpress, xtraeditors

I put a `SpinEdit` control on a `WinForm` and when I click the up and down arrows, it does not do anything.  The only properties I changed on it are:

```
IsFloatValue is false  
MinValue is 1
MaxValue is 99
EditMask = 'N00'
```

Comment: The problem looks strange... I'm afraid that I'm unable to replicate it on my side using he latest version (v12.1) with settings you've described. Could you please attach a full sample code which replicates the issue?

Comment: What is your `spnChartWidth.Properties.Mask.MaskType` ????

Comment: @NiranjanKala - MaskType is numeric.

Comment: @DmitryG - I am using v10.2.8

Answer (score 0):

You must set your parent control to be editable, and You will be able to increment / decrement spin's value...