# Repository spinEdit issue

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have read many articles here about spin edit and just cant solve this problem... I added spin Edit and check Edit repositories in my tree list columns, but when i press spin Edit up/down arrows, value is not changing. And when i click on check Box, it's value is not changing (checked/unchecked). Instead, when i expand node and double Click spin Edit arrows or edit Check Box, node collapses :) tried many things, but cant change value of these repositories...

I found same question here, but noone answerred it:
[DevExpress SpinEdit not incrementing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518041/devexpress-spinedit-not-incrementing)

EDIT: My columns are set not to be readOnly, can be edited, I made my MASK numeric...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.. if anyone have same problem, after u set all properties of Your spinEdit to be editable and stuff, u must also make it's parent control to editable... In my case it is TreeList... So little thing and take so much time, but it is done :)